# Unable to correctly update parent object state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have multiple child components and need to communicate between these siblings. What im currently trying:

Parent has object state and pass setMessageItem as a prop to all children:

```
const [messageItem, setMessageItem] = useState({})
```

Children:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(condition) {
        props.setMessageItem(prevState => ({...prevState, messageData}))
    ..}
    }
}[])
```

However only data from one children reaches this object state. Is there any way I could make it work when two or more children are trying to change the parent's state at the same time?

So the end result would be that messageData would contain data from multiple children at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That useEffect() will only be run once, when the component is instantiated. If you want to use it like that you would do:

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.setMessageItem(prevState => ({ ...prevState, messageData }));
}, [condition]);
```

Then it would trigger on each change of condition.